# Error con python y postgresql

Tags: python

Error:

> Is the server running on host “localhost” (127.0.0.1) and accepting
>   TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

ya instale `postgresql` en su versión reciente pero no queda. Cuando corro la aplicación utilizo `django` `python` (entorno virtual) y me sale el error.

y el `pgadmin4` si me corre en el navegador ya modifique el archivo de la ip: `127.0.0.1` dejandolo en `0.0.0.0`.

O ¿como recomiendan trabajar el `postgresql` utilizo `Debian 9 stretch`?

Comment: Al usar python en un entorno virtual es como si fuese otra máquina, por eso es necesario que modifiques el archivo pg_hba.conf para habilitar el servicio a máquinas remotas.

Answer (score 0):

Me imagino que etas usando un sistema Linux...

Bueno PosgreSQL para poder accederlo tienes que modificar el archivo: pg_hba.conf, buscar la lineas que dice:

```
#"local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
```

la siguiente linea "local   all             all                                     peer" cambiarla por:

```
local   all             all                                     md5
```

reiciniar el servidor con:

```
systemctl restart postgresql.
```

Comment: gracias Igmer ;)